# Limiting records of combinations from 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

looking for some help limiting the results while querying combinations between 2 columns.  Here's an example of the kind of table I am working with..

```
id  name  group  state
1   Bob   A      NY
2   Jim   A      NY
3   Dan   A      NY
4   Mike  A      FL
5   Tim   B      NY
6   Sam   B      FL
7   Brad  B      FL
8   Glen  B      FL
9   Ben   C      FL
```

I am trying to display all records of all combinations of "group" and "state", but limiting to displaying only up to 2 records for each combination.  The result should look like the following..

```
id    name  group   state
1     Bob   A       NY
2     Jim   A       NY
4     Mike  A       FL
5     Tim   B       NY
6     Sam   B       FL
7     Brad  B       FL
9     Ben   C       FL
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you always want the two rows for each `group` and `state` combination with the lowest `id`

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               row_number() over (partition by group, state
                                      order by id asc) rnk
          FROM your_table a)
 WHERE rnk <= 2
```

Of course, since `group` is a reserved word, I assume your column is actually named something else...  You'd need to adjust my query to use the correct column name.